Analog Frequency/Spectrum Shifting; Getting 36Khz to 46Khz sound from AM radio
I thought it would've been better to ask this on the electrical site of stackexchange, but apparently not.
So, my Rats of NIMH fanfiction. All rats and mice (magically) communicate in the same frequency band, but this band is much higher then human hearing! About 36Khz to 46Khz for simplicity sake.
But AM radio only has a bandwidth of about 10Khz analog. So the idea is to use that 0-10Khz frequency range to represent the audio frequencies between 36Khz to 46Khz.
This all would've been developed in the early 1970's in a heavily sanctioned country where vacuum tube equipment would still be common.
Would this work? And what would be the simplest, most cost effective, manner of doing this? Heterodyne up/down conversion seems promising, but I have no idea how THAT works, or how I would figure all the numbers out.
Update: Okay, so maybe I didn't word things too well. So for extra clarification:
Rodent speech is in this ~36Khz to ~46Khz range. This is the outputed audio. (Would probably also need a second secondary winding on the audio output transformer for the piezoelectric "tweeter". Standard magnetic speakers likely wouldn't have the high end frequency response.)
This extra demodulation would be toggleable on the receiver, much like FM Stereo. It would also ONLY be useful for rodent speech, much like how sending music down a telephone or PA results in an experience that is not good.
For compatibility and logistical reasons, and the country being multi specied, so these speech broadcasts need to be broadcast on the MW band.
Also, I have a suspicion that using a subcarrier system to carry more data, much like FM Stereo, might not work out well. Subcarrier systems can be finicky when the received signal is weak. If you ever switched FM Stereo on/off while tuned into a weak station, you'll know what I mean.
Or, maybe a subcarrier system would work satisfactorily.

If they are building their own radios they can choose to use whatever bandwidth they want. Or they can use the 0-10kHz am output to modulate a 36kHz signal to get 36-46kHz.

Bandwidth the width of a band. It can be in the baseband, or it can be shifted up by modulating a carrier. Just note that when modulating a carrier with frequency F with a baseband signal with frequencies 0 to f you will get two sidebands, from F − f to F + f; you will just have to filter out one of them. See the amplitude modulation article on WP for the mathematical details. VTC as not about worldbuilding.

P.S. Mice can hear sounds between about 1 kHz (soprano C, c′′′, C₆) up to some 100 kHz. OK you can probably use a low-pass filter to limit that to maybe 40 to 60 kHz with no great loss, but you definitely cannot filter frequencies below 36 kHz. Use your favorite music player with a graphical equalizer and filter out everything below 1000 or 2000 Hz to realize what the poor mouse would hear if you filtered out the lower half of its hearing range.

"Or they can use the 0-10kHz am output to modulate a 36kHz signal to get 36-46kHz." That is EXACTLY what I meantioned.

I'm joining the close voters because the way you've written your question it sounds very much like you want us to design a circuit for you or, at the least, to open a textbook (because you've not taken the relevant classes or don't want to) and cite a technical solution. Frankly, this does belong on [electronics.se]. You'd get a response if you stripped all the worldbuilding out of it (they don't want to hear about your rats). Are you expecting your rats to speak via modulated AM? Naturally? Intelligent modulation is a form of encoding. There's nothing natural about it.

Maybe this belongs on the ham radio side of stack exchange.  Transmitting ~40kHz audio by radio is trivial.  Single sideband radio transmission is just audio frequency + carrier frequency, reception is then subtracting the carrier frequency to get the audio back.  Humans could pick this up and shift this to their audible range by tuning the carrier such that the audio is in the 1 to 11 kHz range.

If they only use the frequencies from, 36-46 KHz and they do not need absolute pitch then that could use SSB-SC or Single Side Band Suppressed carrier modulation. This would use 10 KHz of bandwidth for the signal, but will not need the 36 KHz offset from the carrier. The receiver has to have a stable oscillator that reproduces the original carrier signal, and then flip the signal in the frequency domain to get conventional AM or FM. An error in the modulation frequency would give a weird pitch shifting distortion, but speech should be recognisable.
If your rats are intelligent, they may add a shifted signal at (say) 30 KHz. This will give a distinctive peak in the frequency spectrum which can be used to stabilise the receiver oscillator, and then the 30 KHz signal could be removed with a notch filter.

Said rats and mice can ear normally, it's just that their speech is around the 36Khz to 46Khz range. The speech just needs to be broadcast over the MW band.
